# Virtualmin Database: connection timed out

Tags: mysql, drupal, virtualmin

I installed virtualmin on a VM instance using google compute engine. I have set up 1 domain and 1 subdomain. On the subdomain i created a database (flexijobs) and added the Drupal tables. Everything works fine except the connection to the database. On loading the drupal index page i get this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

My guess is that the settings are not correct, so in a virtualmin setup, what should i use here, where can i set the password/user, what port should i use, what is the host?

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'flexijobs',
  'username' => 'someUsername',
  'password' => 'somePassword',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'db.somedomain.com',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database through `Webmin > Servers > MariaDB Database Server`
[image]

Note the name, username and password for the database you just made and modify the configuration file to include the information for your database.
The `host` field should be set to `localhost`

```php
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'database_name',
  'username' => 'db_username',
  'password' => 'db_password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```